# DIVs not properly aligned

Tags: html, css

How can I properly align 3 divs side by side?

This is what I am trying to achieve
[image]

Below is the appearance:

[image]

I tried to make all the divs have the same width using float property to left but it doesn't help; I also used `inline-block` with the float property but that didn't help also.

```css
.payment_box .row .col-md-4 {
  position: relative;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .payment_box .row .col-md-4 {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .col-md-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
}
```

```html
<fieldset id="wc-<?php echo esc_attr( $this->id ); ?>-cc-form" class="wc-credit-card-form wc-payment-form row">
  <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_credit_card_form_start', $this->id 
             ); ?>


  <?php if ( $this->inline_cc_form ) { ?>
  <label for="card-element">
       <?php esc_html_e( 'Credit or debit card', 'woocommerce-
                gateway-stripe' ); ?>
       </label>

  <div id="stripe-card-element" class="wc-stripe-elements-
               field">
    <!-- a Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
  </div>
  <?php } else { ?>
  <div class="col-md-4 ">
    <!--<label for="stripe-card-element"><?php esc_html_e( 
               'Card Number', 'woocommerce-gateway-stripe' ); ?> 
        <span class="required">*</span></label>-->
    <div class="stripe-card-group">
      <i class="stripe-credit-card-brand stripe-card-
                     brand" alt="Credit Card"></i>
      <div id="stripe-card-element" class="wc-stripe-
                       elements-field">
        <!-- a Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
    <!--<label for="stripe-exp-element"><?php esc_html_e( 
               'Expiry Date', 'woocommerce-gateway-stripe' ); ?> 
        <span class="required">*</span></label>-->

    <div id="stripe-exp-element" class="wc-stripe-elements-
                    field">
      <!-- a Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
    <!--<label for="stripe-cvc-element"><?php esc_html_e(  
                 'Card Code (CVC)', 'woocommerce-gateway-stripe' ); ?> 
        <span class="required">*</span></label>-->
    <div id="stripe-cvc-element" class="wc-stripe-elements- 
                field">
      <!-- a Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <?php } ?>

  <!-- Used to display form errors -->
  <div class="stripe-source-errors" role="alert"></div>
  <br />
  <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_credit_card_form_end', $this->id );           
            ?>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Set `.row` to `width: 100%;`

Comment: We need to see the HTML. It's probably because you're using `inline-block` and have line breaks between your items, which will put spaces between them. Either use `float: left`, **or** `display: inline-block;` - no need for both. Better yet, **use flexbox**.

Answer (score 2):

You should also provide HTMl for your question so people know what you're trying. I'll provide my answer using `col 1`, `col 2`, and `col 3` so you can see how each works.

It's a good idea to create an initial wrapper for your columns and then create a DIV for them to sit in.

I've provided an example below using three column names so that you can modify percentages and widths to show a different amount on a mobile.

```css
.columnswrapper {
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.columnswrapper {
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
}

.columns {
    min-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.col1 {
    min-width: 33.3%;
    float: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.col1 {
    min-width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
}

.col2 {
    min-width: 33.3%;
    float: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.col1 {
    min-width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
}

.col3 {
    min-width: 33.3%;
    float: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.col3 {
    min-width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="columnswraper">
<div class="columns">

<div class="col1">
<p>Content Goes Here</p>
</div>

<div class="col2">
<p>Content Goes Here</p>
</div>

<div class="col3">
<p>Content Goes Here</p>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

If you wanted them all the same size you could trim your code down like this;

```css
.columnswrapper {
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.columnswrapper {
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
}

.columns {
    min-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.col {
    min-width: 33.3%;
    float: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.col {
    min-width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="columnswraper">
<div class="columns">

<div class="col">
<p>Content Goes Here</p>
</div>

<div class="col">
<p>Content Goes Here</p>
</div>

<div class="col">
<p>Content Goes Here</p>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Or say we wanted two columns to be at 40% and one at 80 but stack them for mobile, we can do this;

```css
.columnswrapper {
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.columnswrapper {
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
}

.columns {
    min-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.col1 {
    min-width: 40%;
    float: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.col1 {
    min-width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
}

.col2 {
    min-width: 40%;
    float: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.col1 {
    min-width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
}

.col3 {
    min-width: 20%;
    float: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.col3 {
    min-width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="columnswraper">
<div class="columns">

<div class="col1">
<p>Content Goes Here</p>
</div>

<div class="col2">
<p>Content Goes Here</p>
</div>

<div class="col3">
<p>Content Goes Here</p>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Keeping `100%` as your width will ensure one column becomes one row on mobile. You can also play around with the `float` property and set a `max-width` for columns the same as the `min-with` to ensure they're always the same size.

Comment: Fixed those now @TylerRoper. There's enough variations in the examples provided to use one or multiple classes as well as set different widths and mobile rules. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. After so many trials I was able to solve it. In  the main div(container) I used `white-space:normal`.

Here is the css for the container

```
.payment_box{
    word-wrap: break-word; 
     white-space: normal;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I'd avoid using that and use the CSS from the other answer provided. Please accept the other answer :)

Comment: @tryingtogethelp, I applied all the answer provided but none worked.